# What are the rules for 'typing' of parameters when explicit integer suffixes are not given?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, constants

For example, if I were to say:

```
#define UINT_DEF 500u
```

Then such a definition would have the type `unsigned int`. However, what is the default rule for when such suffixes are not given? As in

```
#define SOME_DEF 500
```

being placed in the type `int`. That is, at compile-time, if no suffix is given, are the constants *slotted* into the lowest data type in which they fit?

Would, for instance,

```
#define SOME_DEF_2 100
```

Acquire the datatype of `char` since it fits?

I asked a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23858417/using-constants-and-their-associated-modifiers-using-gcc) on a similar topic and had some good responses. However, little was said to the case where no suffix is given. It was said that if a given suffix is requested of the compiler and the assigned value does not fit in such a type then the constant would get promoted, but little else was said about it. I imagine the answer to be something similar to this in that a default casting (perhaps the smallest available) is given to the constants and in such cases where the value should not fit into this default type then a promotion is realized.

And finally, do arithmetic promotion rules still apply as normal for macros? That is, would

```
#define TEST_DEF   5000000/50
#define TEST_DEF_2 5000000/50.0
```

respectively evaluate to 100,000 with a type of `long int` and 100,000.00 of type `float` (assuming 5,000,000 is a long and 50 is an int/char, whatever).

Or in the case:

```
#define TEST_MACRO(x) (16*x)
```

Since 16 is a constant of type `int` most likely, would TEST_MACRO(70000) promote the whole thing to `long`?

Comment: Macros are simply a mechanism of text substitution. So there's no such thing as language rules which "still apply as normal for macros".

Answer (score 5):

```
#define SOME_DEF 500
```

`500` has type `int`. The type of an unsuffixed decimal integer constant is *the first of the corresponding list in which its value can be represented*: `int`, `long`, `long long`.

Then:

```
#define TEST_DEF   5000000/50
#define TEST_DEF_2 5000000/50.0
```

Assuming `5000000` is of type `int` in your system then:

- `5000000/50` is of type `int`
- `5000000/50.0` is of type `double`

Of course the fact that it is macro does not change anything as macros are just relatively simple textual substitutions.

Finally, assuming `70000` is of type `int` then:

`16 * 70000` is also of type `int`

Comment: Great, so no `char` or `short` consideration.

Comment: `5000000/50` is indeed of type `int`, but `1000.0 / TEST_DEF` is not an `int`, and is probably also not what @sherrellbc expects.

Answer (score 3):

Per the [2011 online draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) of the C standard:

> **6.4.4.1 Integer constants**
> ...
> 5 The type of an integer constant is the ﬁrst of the corresponding list in which its value can be represented.
>
> ```
> Suffix           Decimal Constant          Octal or Hexadecimal
>                                                Constant
> -----------------------------------------------------------------
> None             int                       int
>                  long int                  unsigned int
>                  long long int             long int
>                                            unsigned long int
>                                            long long int
>                                            unsigned long long int
> -----------------------------------------------------------------
> u or U           unsigned int              unsigned int
>                  unsigned long int         unsigned long int
>                  unsigned long long int    unsigned long long int
> ------------------------------------------------------------------
> l or L           long int                  long int
>                  long long int             unsigned long int
>                                            long long int
>                                            unsigned long long int
> ------------------------------------------------------------------
> Both u or U      unsigned long int         unsigned long int
> and l or L       unsigned long long int    unsigned long long int
> ------------------------------------------------------------------
> ll or LL         long long int             long long int
>                                            unsigned long long int
> ------------------------------------------------------------------
> Both u or U      unsigned long long int    unsigned long long int
> and ll or LL
> ```

So, if you have a decimal integer constant without a suffix, its type will be the smallest of `int`, `long int`, or `long long int` that can represent that value.

Answer (score 1):

Not so elegant but possible is to cast:

```
#include <inttypes.h> /* For uint16_t */

#define MYFLOAT ((float) 1)

#define MYUNSIGNED16BITINT ((uint16_t) 42.)

#define MYVOIDPOINTER ((void *) 0)
```